# Call LWC function from fullCalendar eventDrop callback

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar in a LWC as a budgeting tool. When events are dragged around the calendar and dropped I want to call a function that is a member of the extended LightningElement class of my LWC.

The function is updateSummaries()... it functions correctly when I manually call it through a refresh button. I cannot find a way to call it from the eventDrop callback provided by fullCalendar. The eventDrop callback handles a call to and APEX class to update some data in SalesForce and that works as expected.

The exact error is: "TypeError: this.updateSummaries is not a function"

I understand that updateSummaries is not a function of fullCalendar but of the LWC class, but I don't know how to the LWC class from the fullCalendar callback?

Current fullCalendar callback:

```
$(ele).fullCalendar({
....

eventDrop : function(info, jsEvent) {
    // APEX Call to save the result of the drop
    setAPEstimate({   
            recId : info.id, 
            epDate : moment(info.start._d).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    }).then(result=>{
        // Update the totals with the result of the drop
        this.updateSummaries();
    }).catch(result=>{
                    console.log(result);
            });
}

....
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Try using an arrow function `eventDrop: (info, jsEvent) => {...}` to ensure that `this` is still bound to the LWC component.

Comment: Wow @PhilW, that was what I needed. Thank you so much! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an arrow function for `eventDrop` to ensure that `this` remains bound as the LWC component:

```
eventDrop : (info, jsEvent) => {
    ...
```

If you use a function declaration the `this` gets rebound as the "global object", typically `window`, or is undefined depending on whether "strict mode" is enforced. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) for a short explanation.